# Register_next_step_handler(в предпоследней функции) не работает, в чем моя ошибка?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

```
import telebot
import configure
import markups
import os
from telebot import types

client = telebot.TeleBot(configure.config['token'])

@client.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def get_text(message):
  client.send_message(message.chat.id, configure.textglav, reply_markup = markups.markup_reply)

@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text', 'document'])
def get_text(message):
  if message.text == ' Оформить карту':
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, "Для оформления заявки необходимо пройти 4 простых шага. Это не займёт много времени. Продолжить?", reply_markup = markups.markup_inline)
  elif message.text == ' Оферта':
    pdffile = open('files/oferta.pdf', 'rb')
    client.send_document(message.chat.id, pdffile, reply_markup=markups.markup_glav)
  elif message.text == '⌚ График работы':
    client.send_message(message.chat.id,"• Время работы: ежедневно с 9: 00 до 21: 00",  reply_markup=markups.markup_glav )
  elif message.text == ' Доверенность':
    doc = open('files/dover.docx', 'rb')
    client.send_document(message.chat.id, doc, reply_markup=markups.markup_glav)
  elif message.text == ' Реферальная программа':
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, "После приобретения нашей услуги вы сможете зарабатывать по 2500 рублей за каждого человека, который оформит у нас карту по вашей реферальной ссылке.", reply_markup = markups.markup_glav)

@client.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
  if call.data == "Оформление заявки":
    pass    

  elif call.data == "образец дов":
    doc = open('files/dover.docx', 'rb')
    client.send_document(call.message.chat.id, doc, reply_markup=markups.markup_glav )

  elif call.data == "www":
    client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, configure.textglav)

  elif call.data == "Инструкция":
    inst = open('files/opencard.pdf', 'rb')
    client.send_document(call.message.chat.id, inst, reply_markup=markups.markup_glav )

@client.message_handler(commands=['appa'])
def app(message):
  msg = client.send_message(message, "☎️ Оставьте ваш номер телефона.")
  client.register_next_step_handler(msg, user_reg)


def user_reg(message):
  client.send_message(message, "Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время. Your NumberPhone{mesе}".format(name=message.text) , reply_markup=markups.markup_glav)



client.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что код не работает?

Comment: register_next_step_handler не работает

Comment: Что значит «не работает»?

Comment: то есть когда я пишу боту /appa он ничего не отвечает

Comment: Если ничего не отвечает, то значит у вас не срабатывает `@client.message_handler(commands=['appa'])`, а значит register_next_step_handler тут вообще ни при чём

Comment: Я точно не проверял, но предполагаю, что ваш `@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text', 'document'])` перехватывает абсолютно все сообщения и соответственно до команды appa проверка просто не доходит. Попробуйте переместить его в самый низ, после всех остальных message_handler'ов и после appa

Comment: спасибо вам большое!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы хотите, чтобы бот отправил сообщение:

```
client.send_message(message.chat.id, "Text")
```

вы первым аргументом указываете идентификатор чата, а не просто message

Исправьте в функциях app и user_reg первый параметр send_message.